# Как правильно достать данные из кортежа

Tags: swift

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно достать первый элемента кортежа если второй удовлетворяет условию? Я сделал обычный способ, но думаю есть более рациональное решение.

```
    var myArray: [(Int, Int)] = [(13, 5), (23, 5), (12, 1), (12, 3), (5, 3)]
var newArray: [Int] = []

for i in myArray {
    if i.1 == 5 {
        newArray.append(i.0)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так можно - сначала отбираем кортежи, где есть 5, с помощью `filter` потом создаем новый массив c помощью `map`

```
newArray = myArray.filter { $0.1 == 5 }.map { $0.0 }
```

Comment: То, что нужно! Благодарю!

Comment: @Near ок тогда поставьте галку как ответ на вопрос